# Java for loop confusion, something I am missing (am a beginner)

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop in java like below,

```
for (int x = cell.getGridX() - 1; x >= 0 && compareCells(cell, getCell(x, cell.getGridY())); --x, ++matches[0]);
```

I need to add more validation to the condition so I changed it to,

```
for (int x = cell.getGridX() - 1; x >= 0; --x) {

        if (compareCells(cell, getCell(x, cell.getGridY()))) {

            ++matches[0];
        }
    }
```

But now it doesn't behave as expected, I cannot figure out why, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: I am learning using Scite text editor I don't think it has a debugger.

Comment: *But now it doesn't behave as expected* so what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Then you should load up Eclipse or something else that *does* have a debugger (you could use [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) if you *really* wanted to... but seriously, learn how to use Eclipse's debugger).  Related: [How to be a Programmer](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html) notice the first skill of the first section.  [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I think you just need to add a `break;` after `++matches[0];`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that downloading eclipse now, never new it existed thanks.

Comment: @Prolog There's Eclipse, Netbeans, and even the Intellij community edition (ultimate edition does a bunch of web development  things you probably don't need at the moment ([comparison of editions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/)).  Pick one, learn how to use it, and you will find it *much* easier to do development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original *for loop*, the `--x` and `++matches[0]` were executed only when `x >= 0` AND `compareCells(cell, getCell(x, cell.getGridY()))` resulted as true.

In your new *for loop*, `--x` is executed every time `x >= 0`, and `++matches[0]` is only executed when the `compareCells()` function returns true. To match the original functionality, it'd look more like the following:

```
for (int x = cell.getGridX() - 1; x >= 0; ;) {
    if (compareCells(cell, getCell(x, cell.getGridY()))) {
        --x;
        ++matches[0];
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: That's an infinite loop if `compareCells` returns false. *Not* a good idea.

Comment: Edited to fix what @ErwinBolwidt brought up.